# Button incrementing a single step in plotly.express slider

Tags: python, button, plotly, slider

I have a graph with multiple subplots controlled by the same slider created with plotly and plotly.express.

Is it possible to add a button of some sort that increments the slider value by 1 and updates all the graphs? Example graph code is provided below with two subplots where the slider iterates over the values of the variable "trial".

I have 5 subplots controlled in this manner over a range of 600 trials and it will be very useful if I could have a more controlled incrementor where I click the button and move the slider a single trial forward and all the graphs are updated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go


# Example Data for plot A
t = 10
npi = 8
nc = 4
data = np.zeros([npi,nc,t])
for c in range(nc):
    data[:,c,:] = np.tile(np.arange(npi).reshape(npi,1),t) +     np.random.normal(0,2,size=[npi,t])

pols = np.arange(npi)
ts = np.arange(t)
cs = np.arange(nc)

mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pols, cs, ts], names=['policy', 'context', 'trial'])
df = pd.Series(index=mi, data=data.flatten())
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns = {0:'probability'})

# Desired animation for plot A
fig1 = px.line(df, x='policy', y='probability',animation_frame='trial',animation_group='context', color="context")



# Example Data for plot B
t = 10
nc = 6
tau = 4
data = np.zeros([nc,tau,t])
for ti in range(tau):
    data[:,ti,:] = np.tile(np.arange(nc).reshape(nc,1),t) + np.random.normal(0,2,size=[nc,t])

conts = np.arange(nc)
ts = np.arange(t)
taus = np.arange(tau)

mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([conts, taus, ts], names=['context', 'timepoint', 'trial'])
df = pd.Series(index=mi, data=data.flatten())
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns = {0:'probability'})

# Desired animation for plot B
fig2 = px.line(df, x='context', y='probability',animation_frame='trial',animation_group='timepoint', color="timepoint")



### combined graph
# integrate the two figures, putting second figure on separate axis
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[t for t in fig1.data] + [t.update(xaxis="x2", yaxis="y2") for t in fig2.data],
    frames=[
        go.Frame(
            name=fr1.name,
            data=[t for t in fr1.data]
            + [t.update(xaxis="x2", yaxis="y2") for t in fr2.data],
        )
        for fr2, fr1 in zip(fig2.frames, fig1.frames)
    ],
    layout=fig1.layout,
)

# now config axes appropriately
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_domain=[0, 0.49],
    xaxis2={"domain": [0.51, 1], "matches": None, "title":{"text":fig2.layout.xaxis.title.text}},
    yaxis2={"matches":"y"},
    showlegend=False,
)
```

P.S. The example was copied over from an answer by another user from a previous question I had asked. I am not sure if there is any community guidelines about this but will adapt as necessary if this is flagged in some way.

Comment: The explanation of the question is unclear and not clear. I tried running the code you provided, but what is 600 units? The button goes forward one step at a time, but now the start button does the same thing.

Comment: By units I mean the unique values that the slider goes over. This corresponds to "trials" in the example graphs. I didn't understand what you mean by this:    "The button goes forward one step at a time, but now the start button does the same thing."     Do you mean that there is a play button added automatically when the graph is generated? This does not work for me because it starts an animation which has to be stopped. I need a button that I click once and it shifts the value for the trial slider to the next trial and updates all the graphs. Is that clearer?

Comment: Isn't it the same with a simple slider? I am referring to [https://plotly.com/python/sliders/#sliders-in-plotly-express](https://plotly.com/python/sliders/#sliders-in-plotly-express) in the official reference.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Yes, that is what the slider does but this is very difficult to control when you are sliding over more than a 100 values, so I need a solution where dragging the slider is not necessary.